# How to cleanly show toast depending on rtk-query's request kind

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I've built a middleware that shows a toast indicating the state of queries started by rtk-query. Using the functions `isPending`, `isFulfilled` and `isRejectedWithValue` I can update the toast to reflect the current state of the query. That's working fine but now I want to differentiate the kind of request cause there are some specific (a little) of them that is preferable not to show any notification, how can I handle that?

This is the actual middleware that handles my use case:

```js
import {
  isFulfilled,
  isPending,
  isRejectedWithValue,
  Middleware,
} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";

const queryStatus: Middleware = () => (next) => (action) => {
  const TOAST_QUERY_ID = "query-status";
  if (isPending(action)) {
    toast("Loading", {
      isLoading: true,
      toastId: TOAST_QUERY_ID,
      type: toast.TYPE.DEFAULT,
    });
  } else if (isFulfilled(action)) {
    toast.update(TOAST_QUERY_ID, {
      render: "Done",
      type: toast.TYPE.SUCCESS,
      isLoading: false,
    });
  } else if (isRejectedWithValue(action)) {
    toast.update(TOAST_QUERY_ID, {
      render: "Error",
      type: toast.TYPE.ERROR,
      isLoading: false,
    });
  }
  return next(action);
};

export default queryStatus;
```

EDIT: One approach (I'm looking for something cleaner):

```js
import {
  isFulfilled,
  isPending,
  isRejectedWithValue,
  Middleware,
} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";

const queryStatus: Middleware = () => (next) => (action) => {
  const TOAST_QUERY_ID = "query-status";
  if (isPending(action)) {
    toast("Loading", {
      isLoading: true,
      toastId: TOAST_QUERY_ID,
      type: toast.TYPE.DEFAULT,
    });
  } else if (isFulfilled(action)) {
    if (action.meta.arg.type === "mutation") {
      toast.update(TOAST_QUERY_ID, {
        render: "Done",
        type: toast.TYPE.SUCCESS,
        isLoading: false,
        autoClose: 200,
      });
    } else {
      toast.update(TOAST_QUERY_ID, {
        isLoading: false,
        autoClose: 100,
      });
    }
  } else if (isRejectedWithValue(action)) {
    toast.update(TOAST_QUERY_ID, {
      render: "Error",
      type: toast.TYPE.ERROR,
      isLoading: false,
      autoClose: 3000,
    });
  }
  return next(action);
};

export default queryStatus;
```

Although this approach only handles the mutations differently from queries and not specific endpoints.